# JavaScript to export code inside a div element?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a web document that contains a `div` element.

That `div` element contains an `svg` child element (which itself contains SVG primitives: `text`, `path`, etc.).

Ultimately, I would like to export that `svg` element into a proper, self-contained SVG document. (I can then run that SVG document through `imagemagick` and make publication-quality figures.)

Is there JavaScript that will "dump" the contents of the `div` element with the requisite `<?xml>` header into a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html) plugin, in particular the toSVG() method in the SVG Defs section.  You won't be able to save the document via Javascript/jQuery, but you should be able to open a new window with the document contents and use the browser's save functionality to save the text document to a file.